# Not able to solve this combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There is a n*n square grid, consisting of n^2 small squares, each is to be colored either red or blue.

now you have to find the number of ways of coloring given this condition.

"Every distinct square of size k (1<=k<=n) should satisfy the property the number of blue-colored and red-colored squares differ by almost 1. "

But I am still not able to count the total ways.

I was thinking of using induction like given ways to color (n-1)*(n-1) grid how to get at (n)*(n).

But am not able to reach the solution

for 2 the answer comes to 6(ways to choose 2 things from 4).

for 3 it comes to 10(mp)

Please help

Thanks!!

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Comment: a friend of mine gave it to me not sure where he got it from, some obscure book or exam maybe

Comment: A closed form is unlikely.

Comment: Why? @quasi........

Comment: This question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4002020/balanced-2019-times-2019-grids-bmo-2020-round-2).

Comment: @free electron: Your claim that it suffices to check the condition for all $2{\,\times\,}2$ and $3{\,\times\,}3$ sub-blocks is false.$\;$For example, for the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the condition holds for all $2{\,\times\,}2$ and $3{\,\times\,}3$ sub-blocks, but fails at the  $5{\,\times\,}5$ level.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Will Orrick :)

Comment: @quasi thanks for pointing this out , i shall edit the questions

Answer (score 1):

I tackled your problem with [Minizinc](https://www.minizinc.org/).

```
int: n = 10;
set of int: N = 1..n;
bool: Red = true;
bool: Blue = false;

array[N, N] of var bool: grid;

constraint 
    forall(k in N) (
        forall(top in 1..n-k+1) (
            forall(left in 1..n-k+1) (
              abs(2*sum([grid[top+row,left+col] | row in 0..k-1, col in 0..k-1]) - k*k) <= 1
    )));
```

The grid cells are modelled as an array of Boolean variables.
The number $B$ of blue cells and the number of red cells must add to $k^2$.
Therefore, the constraint can be written as

$$|2B - k^2| \le 1 $$

The number of solutions is:

```
n  #solutions
1      2   (one red or one blue cell)
2      6
3     10
4     18
5     26
6     42
7     58
8     90
9    122
10   186
11   250
12   378
13   506
14   762
15  1018
..   ...
20  6138
```

Comment: Thanks for this!!

Comment: If you omit the initial entry, the first differences appear to yield successive powers of two, in pairs.  Does that pattern persist for the values you omitted for $n\in\{11,\dots,19\}$?

Comment: Shouldn't the numbers of solutions be $2$ for $n=1$? As Rob Pratt said, the first differences of your sequence are powers of $2$: $$4,4,8,8,16,16,32,32,\ldots.$$ Summing the geometric series, the expression for $n$ odd is $2^{(n+5)/2}-6$ and the expression for $n$ even $3\cdot 2^{(n+2)/2}-6$. This holds for the number of solutions for $n=20$ in your table. You can, of course, combine these to get an expression for all $n$.