# Number of balanced ways to color a $2019\times2019$ grid

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> A $2019\times2019$ square grid is made up of $2019^2$ unit cells. Each cell is coloured either black or white. A colouring is called balanced if, within every square subgrid made up of $k^2$ cells for $1\le k\le2019$, the number of black cells differs from the number of white cells by at most one. How many different balanced colourings are there?
> (*Two colourings are different if there is at least one cell which is black in exactly one of them*.)$\newcommand\p{~~\bullet~~}$

This is [$\sf2020~BMO~Round~2,P3$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h2040995p14437160), but the link had got no answers!  I have a few ideas though,

$\p$A balanced coloring needn't be like the chessboard. (So the answer isn't $2$) For example, a $3\times3$ grid colored like $\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline1&0&1\\\hline1&0&1\\\hline0&1&0\\\hline\end{array}$ is balanced. And for larger grids the kinds strange balanced methods will only be more.

$\p$The problem is highly inductive. In a balanced colored grid, any sub grid is also balanced colored. And we could try to start from smaller grids. For example, we can find all balanced colorings of a $3\times3$ grid.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4002020/balanced-2019-times-2019-grids-bmo-2020-round-2?rq=1

Comment: @Dstarred Thanks.